# TableView has left margin in Xcode Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview

I have a Table view controller with a table view in it in `Swift`. The `TableView` works fine(it loads the correct amount of data into the table and everything) but there is a `margin/padding/gap down` the left-hand side of the screen that can be seen in the image below. Any suggestions on how I resolve this?

[image: Screenshot of issue]

Comment: Have you done anything in code yet? Or is this entirely created within a storyboard/xib so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make constraints like this , by un checking constraint to margins

[image]

Comment: Slightly off topic, but what did you use to record the steps above?

Comment: search for GIPHY for MAC